# Prove that the function in the domain of Z is a high pass filter

Tags: signal-processing, z-transform

I need prove that the function
\begin{equation}
L(z) = 1-z^{-1} 
\end{equation}
is a high pass filter, but I have not much understanding of the $z$ transform and what really the $z$ domain is.
So how could I prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to go from a (discrete time) signal's $z$-transform to its DTFT, substitute $z = e^{jw}$.  So, we have
$$
L(e^{jw}) = 1 - e^{-jw}
$$
We want to check how $|L(e^{jw})|$ for different values of $w$.  We have
$$
\begin{align}
\left| 
L(e^{jw})
\right| &= 
\left| 
(1 - \cos(w)) + j\sin(w)
\right| =
\sqrt{
(1 - \cos(w))^2 + \sin^2(w)
}\\
&= \sqrt{\sin^2(w) + \cos^2(w) - 2 \cos(w) + 1}
= \sqrt{2(1-\cos(w))}
\end{align}
$$
Why does this magnitude spectrum correspond to that of a high-pass filter?  Try graphing it from $-\pi$ to $\pi$.